# Can I embed React-three-fiber in an Angular app

Tags: reactjs, angular

I have built an angular app that makes pretty extensive use of three.js. Since I built that app, React-three-fiber has been developed and I love it. I don't want to rebuild the app in react. Is it possible to embed react and thus react-three-fiber in an angular app?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** It doesn't make sense.

**Full answer:** React-three-fiber is a renderer for three.js. It merely expresses threejs in JSX:

```
<mesh />
```

represents

```
new THREE.Mesh()
```

If you want to use React components in Angular you might use a module like [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact/tree/master/examples/jsx-transformer). However, you would have to convert any JSX code to code that does not use JSX as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). This would defeat the purpose of r3f and you would basically just re-create r3f for Angular.